Does ubuntu 22.04 support the Node.js 20 version?
i'm using the node.js 12 as default supported version on ubuntu 22.04 and i want to upgrade it to 20 as the last LTS. but i need to know if it'is supported and can easly been installed or it needs external sources ?

Looking at https://nodejs.org/en/download/prebuilt-binaries it is my understanding that the node.js project itself provide precompiled binaries which run under any Linux.

According to Ubuntu packages the latest version is 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.4, which is node 12.22.9 with security fixes applied by Debian maintainers. If you want newer versions you're better off using nvm or alternatives.

Short answer yes it supports
You need to use example sudo npm install -g n then
sudo n stable

That is an external source.
